# Moving files through a crontab task doesn't work, but works if is executed manually

Tags: unix, cron, ksh

I'm trying to move files crontab to get that scheduled but the crontab is not moving the files. If I do it manually, it works... do you know what could be the possible reason? This is what I have:

```
13,29 * * * * mv $(grep -l "File was not FOUND" /home/user/test*) /home/user/temp
```

If I execute the following line it works without any problem:

```
mv $(grep -l "File was not FOUND" /home/user/test*) /home/user/temp
```

Comment: Try a "set -x; " right before "mv" to see exactly what command is run - iirc some cron implementations do their own (semibroken) parsing instead of blindly passing the string to the shell

Comment: but how is suppose to see what it does if is executed with the cron, output is not displayed in the console.

Comment: "set -x" prints commands as they are executed, and cron is supposed to mail that to you - try adding an "echo test" that gets run every minute, wait for a minute, you should have mail in /var/mail/ (or whatever you configured)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, cron jobs are run using `/bin/sh`. You should be able to set the shell to use by adding it just before your job like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
13,29 * * * * mv $(grep -l "File was not FOUND" /home/user/test*) /home/user/temp
```

...or whichever shell you like.

Alternatively, if your crond does not support that notation, you may explicitly invoke the shell you like, using its `-c` argument:

```
13,29 * * * * bash -c 'mv $(grep -l "File was not FOUND" /home/user/test*) /home/user/temp'
```

Notice the enclosing single quotes. They are required as the whole command must be a single argument to the shell.

Yet another way would be to convert your command to use plain old bourne shell (sh) syntax, which I believe should be:

```
13,29 * * * * mv `grep -l "File was not FOUND" /home/user/test*` /home/user/temp
```

...using backticks for command substitution.

Comment: When I do that, I'm getting this error:

SHELL=/bin/bash
crontab: error on previous line; unexpected character found in line.
crontab: errors detected in input, no crontab file generated.

Comment: Interesting. I added another way to get the same result. Out of curiosity, what platform are you using?

Comment: that's SunOS  5.10 Generic_150400-28

Comment: @JavierSalas solaris is known because their /bin/sh is NOT posix, their posix shell is /usr/xpg4/bin/sh

Comment: Nice @spectras the 2nd solution works for me using quotes

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple Schell script. add  `#!/bin/bash` at the top.

```
#!/bin/bash
mv /your/source/file/path /target/path
# In your case something like below should work.
# make sure your path is absalute path, starting from root folder.
# mv $(grep -l "File was not FOUND" /home/user/test*) /home/user/temp
```

and then execute above shell script in crontab like below.

```
13,29 * * * * /path/to/file/movescript.sh
```

make sure that your script have execute permission, and the user can move files. better run the script manually before scheduling

`chmod +x movescript.sh` will add execute permission.